# React: Button switch changing state

Tags: reactjs

This might be very simple, but I am absolutely stuck on it. I have three buttons on my page, `button1`, `button2`, `button3`.

Each button must act independently. When rendered, there is a component state `sum = 0`. When buttons are clicked, an `onClick` function needs to `+1` (add 1) to the state `sum`, or `-1` (subtract 1) form the state if the button has been clicked already.

What would be the best way of implementing this?

So far, the component is the following:

```
export class Sum extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            sum: 0
        }
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({ sum: this.state.sum + 1}) // needs to do -1 if the button is clicked already
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button1</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button2</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button3</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: @Dineshundefined updated.

Comment: your only one state sum and there three buttons. how do you separate three buttons which button is clicked?

Comment: That's what I want to do, and that's why I have a problem. Because if I will have 76 buttons, I don't want to keep 76 states.

Answer (score 0):

keep an array with booleans for each button.so initially it would be like this

`this.state = {buttonClicked:[false,false,false]}` in the constructor

then on the button onclick. you update the corresponding buttons boolean to true.

and then finally add 1 to the sum if boolean false. or else minus 1.

Comment: And buttons need to act independently. I.E. if button1 adds +1, and button2 has been already clicked, if clicking on button2 again, it will remove the 1 that has been added previously by button1.

Comment: you can pass parameters to the function handleClick in order to identify which button was clicked. i can suggest you other ways but the above is sufficient enough i guess. :)

Comment: And what if I have 25 buttons? Won't work in that case.

Comment: if you have more number of buttons then use an loop to create an array of that many buttons. you only need a small change for this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Sum extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        sum: 0, buttonClicked:[false,false,false]
    }
}

handleClick(buttonNumber) {

  if(this.state.buttonClicked[buttonNumber-1]){
   this.setState({sum:this.state.sum-1})
  else
   this.setState({sum:this.state.sum+1})

  let x = this.state.buttonClicked; 
  x[buttonNumber-1] = true;   //for updating buttonClicked array
  this.setState({buttonClicked:x})

}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,1)}>button1</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,2)}>button2</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,3)}>button3</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your code contains bugs, not a good practice of answering, but thank you, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Just check for existing state and change accordingly.

Here is the working code https://codesandbox.io/s/14jq6kyyw7

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export class Sum extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sum: 0
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.sum == 1) {
      this.setState({ sum: -1 }); 
    } else {
      this.setState({ sum: 1 }); 
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.sum}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>button1</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>button2</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>button3</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
render(<Sum />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted not to set the state to 1 or -1, but add 1 and subtract 1 from it. Hence, the maximum value the sum state can have is 3, and the minimum state value is 0.